# User delegated SAS token

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, azure-storage

I am using .NET core 3.0

I am trying to create a daemon application, which reads and writes files in a storage blob container. I would like to use "user delegated SAS token" as this seems to be the best practice.

I tried following the instructions in the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-dotnet), but ran into trouble. I believe the code is supposed to write out some of the properties of the user delegation key, but in my case it doesn't do anything.

I am logged with my own account on browser (google Chrome), which has Owner role of the Subscription.
I am suspecting that the authentication process is not right, and tried some stuff (such as assigning roles to an application, then using TokenCredential instead of DefaultAzureCredential()), but nothing changed.

This is the actual code. I copied and pasted the sample code , and just added `await blobClient.GetPropertiesAsync()` for debugging.
The result of the code is just "before GetPropertiesAsync()", and no errors.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Storage.Sas;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

namespace TestUserDelegatedSAS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String accountName = "deleted";
            String containerName = "deleted";
            String blobName = "deleted.txt";
            GetUserDelegationSasBlob(accountName, containerName, blobName).GetAwaiter();

        }

        async static Task<Uri> GetUserDelegationSasBlob(string accountName, string containerName, string blobName)
        {
            // Construct the blob endpoint from the account name.
            string blobEndpoint = string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net", accountName);

            // Create a new Blob service client with Azure AD credentials.  
            BlobServiceClient blobClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(blobEndpoint),
                                                                    new DefaultAzureCredential());

            Console.WriteLine("before GetPropertiesAsync()");
            await blobClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("after GetPropertiesAsync()");

            // Get a user delegation key for the Blob service that's valid for seven days.
            // You can use the key to generate any number of shared access signatures over the lifetime of the key.
            UserDelegationKey key = await blobClient.GetUserDelegationKeyAsync(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                                                                                DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7));

            // Read the key's properties.
            Console.WriteLine("User delegation key properties:");
            Console.WriteLine("Key signed start: {0}", key.SignedStartsOn);
            Console.WriteLine("Key signed expiry: {0}", key.SignedExpiresOn);
            Console.WriteLine("Key signed object ID: {0}", key.SignedObjectId);
            Console.WriteLine("Key signed tenant ID: {0}", key.SignedTenantId);
            Console.WriteLine("Key signed service: {0}", key.SignedService);
            Console.WriteLine("Key signed version: {0}", key.SignedVersion);
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Create a SAS token that's valid for one hour.
            BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
            {
                BlobContainerName = containerName,
                BlobName = blobName,
                Resource = "b",
                StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
            };

            // Specify read permissions for the SAS.
            sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read);

            // Use the key to get the SAS token.
            string sasToken = sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(key, accountName).ToString();

            // Construct the full URI, including the SAS token.
            UriBuilder fullUri = new UriBuilder()
            {
                Scheme = "https",
                Host = string.Format("{0}.blob.core.windows.net", accountName),
                Path = string.Format("{0}/{1}", containerName, blobName),
                Query = sasToken
            };

            Console.WriteLine("User delegation SAS URI: {0}", fullUri);
            Console.WriteLine();
            return fullUri.Uri;
        }

        private static async Task ReadBlobWithSasAsync(Uri sasUri)
        {
            // Try performing blob operations using the SAS provided.

            // Create a blob client object for blob operations.
            BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(sasUri, null);

            // Download and read the contents of the blob.
            try
            {
                // Download blob contents to a stream and read the stream.
                BlobDownloadInfo blobDownloadInfo = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(blobDownloadInfo.Content, true))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Read operation succeeded for SAS {0}", sasUri);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            catch (RequestFailedException e)
            {
                // Check for a 403 (Forbidden) error. If the SAS is invalid,
                // Azure Storage returns this error.
                if (e.Status == 403)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Read operation failed for SAS {0}", sasUri);
                    Console.WriteLine("Additional error information: " + e.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I am really stuck here, and any piece of advice is very much appreciated.
Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: I have changed the authentication part to ```BlobServiceClient blobClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(blobEndpoint), new InteractiveBrowserCredential());``` and it worked! I still don't understand why though. Any piece of suggestment or advice will be a great help.

Comment: The ```DefaultAzureCredential``` will you use your MSI, could you please check if your MSI have enough permissions?

Comment: I tested this code from my laptop, so there must have been no MSI available. I will test this from a VM and get back to you.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: If you are writing a non interactive Daemon why are you using delegated user access? Would it not make more sense to use Managed Identity for this? Or do you need to assign specific access to the Daemon only when granted by a user somewhere up-stream? Otherwise I think you would use Managed Identity and grant your Daemon the necessary rights. When MIS didn't work, was that locally? had you used az login to authenticate with the necessary rights to the storage account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my research, if you want to request the user delegation key, a security principal must be assigned the **Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/generateUserDelegationKey** action. Meawhile,  the following built-in RBAC roles include the Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/generateUserDelegationKey action. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas#assign-permissions-with-rbac).

- Contributor
- Storage Account Contributor
- Storage Blob Data Contributor
- Storage Blob Data Owner
- Storage Blob Data Reader
- Storage Blob Delegator

Besides, please note that if you use `Storage Blob Data Contributor`,`Storage Blob Data Owner`,
`Storage Blob Data Reader` and
`Storage Blob Delegator`, we cannot get account properties with these role. Becasue these role have no permissions to do action on account level. In other words, we cannot call method `BlobServiceClient.GetPropertiesAsync`. For more details, please refer to the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-contributor)

The detailed steps are as below

1. Create a service principal

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name ServicePrincipalName \
    --role "Storage Blob Data Reader" \
--scope 

</subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>
```

2. Code

```
var delegationKey = await blobServiceClient.GetUserDelegationKeyAsync(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7));
        BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
        {
            BlobContainerName = containerName,
            BlobName = blobName,
            Resource = "b",
            StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
            ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
        };
        sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read);
        Console.WriteLine(sasBuilder.Permissions);
        var sasQueryParams = sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(delegationKey, storageProviderSettings.AccountName).ToString();
        UriBuilder sasUri = new UriBuilder()
        {
            Scheme = "https",
            Host = string.Format("{0}.blob.core.windows.net", storageProviderSettings.AccountName),
            Path = string.Format("{0}/{1}", containerName, blobName),
            Query = sasQueryParams
        };
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I re-checked the roles assigned, and my user ID had the Service Administrator which should include all the roles necessary (please correct me if I am wrong). My application on the other hand, did not have the account level role, so that explains why the ```BlobServiceClient.GetPropertiesAsync``` failed. Thank you again for your great input.